# SaltStack : Unable to install a salt dependency library manually

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to install a library pycryptodome on the salt master using pip and post installation version report doesn't show it correctly.  However what i notice is the the version of the new installation get updated against pycrypto and not pycryptodome.

Do i need to reload anything.  Or is there another way to install it ?

Below the version report.

```
ro@salt:~$ sudo salt --versions-report 
Salt Version:
           Salt: 3000.2

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: 2.4.2
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: 0.6.4
      gitpython: 1.0.1
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.6.2
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 3.5.2 (default, Apr 16 2020, 17:47:17)
   python-gnupg: 0.3.8
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 15.2.0
          smmap: 0.9.0
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.4

System Versions:
           dist: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
         locale: ANSI_X3.4-1968
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.4.0-178-generic
         system: Linux
        version: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
```

Below report is after pip3 installation of pycryptodome. You can notice the version of pycrypto changed to 3.9.7 from 2.6.1

```
ro@salt:~$  salt --versions-report 
Salt Version:
           Salt: 3000.2

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: 2.4.2
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: 0.6.4
      gitpython: 1.0.1
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.6.2
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 3.9.7
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 3.5.2 (default, Apr 16 2020, 17:47:17)
   python-gnupg: 0.3.8
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 15.2.0
          smmap: 0.9.0
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.4

System Versions:
           dist: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
         locale: ANSI_X3.4-1968
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.4.0-178-generic
         system: Linux
        version: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial

ro@salt:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with help from my colleague.  The documentation for pycryptodome says that its drop-in replacement for pycrypto which is the reason it displays that way.  Installing pycryptodomex will recognize pycryptodome as a standalone package.

```
ro@salt:~$ sudo salt --versions-report
Salt Version:
           Salt: 3000.2
Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: 2.4.2
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: 0.6.4
      gitpython: 1.0.1
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.6.2
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: Not Installed
   pycryptodome: 3.9.7
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 3.5.2 (default, Apr 16 2020, 17:47:17)
   python-gnupg: 0.3.8
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 15.2.0
          smmap: 0.9.0
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.4
System Versions:
           dist: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.4.0-178-generic
         system: Linux
        version: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
```